# Kafka Source Connector - How to pass the schema from String (json)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I've developed a custom source connector for an external REST service.
I get JSONs, convert them to `org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct` with manually defined schema (`SchemaBuilder`) and wrap all this to `SourceRecord`.
All of this is for one entity only, but there a dozen of them.

My new goal is to make this connector universal and parametrize the schema. The idea is to get the schema as String (json) from configs or external files and pass it to `SourceRecord`, but it only accepts `Schema` objects.

Is there any simple/good ways to convert String/json to Schema or even pass String schema directly?

Comment: I finally generated the right question for google and almost found an answer for myself.

There is a second part of answer [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/WBdl8ksD9qo)

Now I'm looking for a way to transform json to avro schema. I'll answer with details my own question when figure it out completely

Comment: Curious what you added over this REST connector - https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest

Comment: Incremental load with pagination.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [JSON to Avro converter](https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter), however, if you are already building a Struct/Schema combination, then you shouldn't need to do anything, as the Converter classes in Kafka Connect can handle the conversion for you

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure you have correctly understood the situation. I'm trying to build SourceRecord with external schema, without building it with SchemaBuilder

Comment: I never said to use SchemaBuilder. What do you mean by "external schema"?

Comment: My point here is that you don't need your own Struct. Convert the JSON to Avro, then you can use `AvroData.toConnectRecord` and return the results of that

Comment: By external schema I mean that my connector gets Schema as a string parameter in json format.

Comment: I'm worried about using internal classes like ```AvroData```, it's not a robust solution, imho. So I've ended up with idea of parsing the String schema for my own and build schema with ```SchemaBuilder```. It seems quite simple to do.

Comment: It's not internal. The HDFS connector uses it to convert Schema records into Parquet format